# null exception in listview SQLite

Tags: android

I am trying to get a value from database and add it to an array to show it in a listview.
Here is my code.

When I check on arg1 I got the value, I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

---

highscore method

```
list_score=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.score_list);//listview
        //get DB
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            highscoreDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HIGHSCORE"+(i+3)+"(" +
                    "TIME long(9),MOVE integer(4),GRID integer(2));"
                   );
            Cursor gethighscorealter=highscoreDB.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM HIGHSCORE"+(i+3)+
                       " ORDER BY TIME asc, MOVE asc ;"
                       , null);
            if(gethighscorealter.getCount()>0){
                gethighscorealter.moveToFirst();
                timer= gethighscorealter.getLong(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("TIME")); 
                move = gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("MOVE"));
                grid = gethighscorealter.getInt(gethighscorealter.getColumnIndex("GRID"));
                arg1[i]=timer;
                arg2[i]=move;
                arg3[i]=grid;
            }else{
                arg1[i]=1;
                arg2[i]=1;
                arg3[i]=i+3;
            }
        }
            list_score.setAdapter(new IntRangeAdapter(this,R.layout.score,arg1, arg2, arg3));


                highscoreview();
```

highscoreview method

```
AlertDialog.Builder showhighscore =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.high_score_list, null);//score
            showhighscore.setCancelable(false);
            showhighscore.setTitle(" ");
            showhighscore.setView(layout);
            showhighscore.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon);
            showhighscore.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.cancel();
                    onResume();
                }
            });
               showhighscore.show();
```

IntRangeAdapter class

```
public class IntRangeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private int mItemResource;
        private long[] time= new long[10];
        private int[] move=new int[10];
        private int[] grid=new int[10];

        public IntRangeAdapter(Context context, int itemLayout,long[] arg1,int[] arg2,int[] arg3) {
           mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mItemResource = itemLayout;
            time=arg1;
            move=arg2;
            grid=arg3;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
               convertView = mInflater.inflate(mItemResource, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            tv.setText(""+time[position]);
            tv2.setText(move[position]);
            tv3.setText(grid[position]);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

my log cat

```
06-26 00:43:06.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 00:43:06.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1817): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 00:43:06.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at skripsi.slidame.PuzzleActivity.highscore(PuzzleActivity.java:283)
06-26 00:43:06.639: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at skripsi.slidame.PuzzleActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(PuzzleActivity.java:147)
```

`PuzzleActivity.java:283` is `list_score.setAdapter(new IntRangeAdapter(this,R.layout.score,arg1, arg2, arg3));`

Comment: It seems `list_score` is `null`. Are you sure that `score_list` is a `ListView` in the xml you are using? Put a breakpoint right after the line where you initialize it and see if it is `null` there

Comment: wew ur right,when i check if(list_score!=null),i got list_score null..
but i have score_list in other xml,i cant freely using it? what should i do?

Comment: In what "other xml"? It should be in the one that you set in `onCreate()`

Comment: high_score_list.xml , on create()? setcontentview?

Comment: It should be in the xml when you call `setContentView(R.layout.high_score_list);` If this `extends ListActivity` you can also use `getListView().setAdapter(...)`

Comment: no, what i want is, main.xml still showing, and i want showing high_score_list.xml in my alert dialog using inflate

Comment: Oh, you want your `listView` in the dialog

Comment: I have added an answer. See if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand what you are doing a little better, an easier way than using a `Dialog` would be to make it an `Activity` and you can give it a `Dialog Theme`. Just add to your `<activity>` tag in `manifest`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

But the underlying problem here is that you are trying to access `score_list` in your `main.xml` but it exists in your `high_score_list.xml` which you use for your `Dialog`. You need to either do my first suggestion or move the code for your `listView` into your `Dialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder showhighscore =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)   
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.high_score_list, null);//score
        ListView list_score = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.score_list);  // add this line here and set adapter here
        list_score.setAdapter(new IntRangeAdapter(this,R.layout.score,arg1, arg2, arg3));
        showhighscore.setCancelable(false);
        showhighscore.setTitle(" ");
        showhighscore.setView(layout);
        showhighscore.setIcon(R.drawable.men
```

Comment: same..
in row `list_score.setAdapter(new IntRangeAdapter(this,R.layout.score,arg1, arg2, arg3));`

`06-26 01:41:21.989: E/AndroidRuntime(4209): java.lang.NullPointerException
`

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to know why, without seeing the entire program.

I suggest that you try to run the app in debug mode. Work backwards from the place where the null pointer occurs. See if your assumptions in the program make sense.

I suppose, without having more information, that list_score is null, and so trying to refer to one of its methods doesn't work.